# I need to select the last Column of an excel file C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to select the last column of an excel, but when I try to do that I always get an exception saying that the value I'm trying to get is Null.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
var lastColumn2 = foglio.LastColumnUsed();
var lastColumn = lastColumn2.Worksheet.ActiveCell.Address.ColumnNumber;
```

This gets the number of the last used column.
This code worked fine till today with an excel that had some rows colored.

*(MY OPINION)*
The fact that some rows are colored caused the "ActiveCell" parameter to be null. The exception is caused by that.
The Exception I'm getting:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 
'You're referring to a not set value of an object.'
```

The issue is that when I set the color to *none* and I color the row again and run the code... it works just fine as nothing happened before.
So at this point I don't know what is causing the issue here....
Even if I color the rows again the program starts working again but if I don't it crashes.

Is there a way to fix that?
Or is there a better way to get the index of the last column used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but i think that it helps:

```
Excel.Range last = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1", last);

int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
int lastUsedColumn = last.Column;
```